# How to fix this java code to render result once those two values are written

Tags: java, android

What I want to is once both `edt_weight` & `edit_height` written, setoneditoraction, because now people need to press ok once they put in the weight to show the result.
I want the result to be shown instantly when those two value are entred by user.

My code is:

```
    edt_gen=findViewById(R.id.edt_gen);
**edt_weight**.setFilters(new InputFilter[]);
**edt_height**.setFilters(new InputFilter[]);
edt_weight.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what you are asking here. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on how to ask a a good question (and therefore get people to help you)

Comment: Is it allowed to send apk here, to ask questions about it?

Comment: It's the code that we are interested in - and only snippets of it